# JDBC insert statement error

Tags: sql, jdbc, derby

I cannot seem to figure out why it keep giving me this: executeQuery method can not be used for update. The way my code works is it takes in text from 5 jTextFields then converted to string double and int values. These values are sent to a method which will be pasted below. The problem is the sql statement is not working correctly at least I believe that is the problem. The columns are correct as well.

```
try{
    String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Comics";
    String uName = "Brenton";
    String uPass = "password";

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
    Statement stat = con.createStatement();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO LIBRARY(TITLE, ISSUE, PRICE, PUBLISHER, YEAR_ISSUED)" + "VALUES( '" + title + "', " + issue + ", " + price + ", '" + publisher + "', " + year + ")";

    ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(sql);
    }
    catch(SQLException err){

        System.out.println(err.getMessage());

    }
```

Comment: Do **not** concatenate values into your SQL like that. Please learn how to properly use a `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate error (I think) is that your insert statement has no spaces between the end of the column names and the start of the `VALUES` keyword.  But all this could be avoided if you used prepared statements:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO LIBRARY(TITLE, ISSUE, PRICE, PUBLISHER, YEAR_ISSUED) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, title);
ps.setString(2, issue);
ps.setDouble(3, price);
ps.setString(4, publisher);
ps.setYear(5, year);
```

Note several obvious advantages here to this approach.  First, you may write your insert query as a single string, with no concatenation.  This helps avoid the mistake you made with whitespace.  Second, statements do the work of escaping the string values (and any other value) properly.

Answer (score 0):

What "executeQuery method can not be used for update" means is as follows:

Some SQL statements are used for queries. A SQL query is generally a `SELECT` statement, and it returns a set of rows from a database, which you process using a a JDBC `ResultSet`.

A SQL update is an `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` statement, and it modifies rows in the database, but does not return any rows back to you (rather it returns the **number** of rows that you modified).

So, you can query, or you can update.

To query, you use `executeQuery`, and you get back a `ResultSet`.

To update, you use `executeUpdate`, and you get back a `int`.

For `executeQuery`, you pass a `SELECT` SQL statement.

For `executeUpdate`, you pass a `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` SQL statement.

In your code, you are trying to perform a `INSERT` SQL statement, but you are calling `executeQuery`.